# Fig Tree Worms? Solution?

Tags: trees, figs

[image]

Hi!

I’m hoping someone can help me with a fig tree problem. We are located in Lebanon.

There seems to be something resembling sawdust around the tree bark. This is my parents’ garden and I am relying on their verbal information about symptoms. No worms have been seen as far as I understand. All we have all seen is this sawdust.

It would be great if someone could verify what the issue is, or if there is an issue at all. If you do recognize anything in this image that verifies what the problem is, it would be great if you could suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The sawdust, often called "frass" when it is the result of an insect boring into wood and ejecting the dust through the entry hole, could be the result of the [Figtree Longhorn Beetle](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/523992-Phryneta-spinator), a species which lays its eggs on fig trees among other species. The larvae then chew their way into the tree. Once in the tree they go deep and so you will see only the result of the chewing. Adults emerge and escape. This species of beetle is seen mostly in Africa, so Lebanon might be on the fringe of the observed area of activity.

Some control can be achieved through killing the larvae by puncturing them with a springy wire poked into the holes. The tunnels may be deep. Also if the damage is on a specific branch you can prune it off and then make it hard for adults to lay more eggs on what remains of the tree.